# OrangeHRM_Admin_Menus_List

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

On the OrangeHRM website(URL - https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/admin/viewSystemUsers), I am trying to fetch the list of menus (user management, job, organization, qualification, nationalities, corporate banking, configuration) under the Admin Menu(See in the snippet below).

Please help me find the XPath to get those lists.

[image]

Comment: Please always provide a minimum reproducible work/code snippets in order to reproduce the error/problem and thus provide you some way around to solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks,Im able to find xpath of the list of menus available in the dashboard of orangehrm,"(//*[contains(@class,'oxd-main-menu')])[5]//following::li"

Answer (score 0):

This is the XPath expression you need to locate the desired menus:

```
//nav[@class='oxd-topbar-body-nav']//li
```

[image]